# json_decode returns null on 1 server. json is valid an no json errors

Tags: php, json

I realize there's been a few questions on this, and looking at the various answers I still can't find a solution.

I've got some JSON that I'm calling from a web service over which I have no control. JSONLINT however shows that the return json is valid.

If I dump the contents of my CURL call and paste that response in JSONLINT again it is valid json.

As soon as I try json_decode on the result and dump that it becomes NULL.

At first I thought it might be a malformed character etc. but this doesn't appear to be the case a) because JSONLINT validates the json and b) because if I run the exact some call on another server it works and c)json_last_error returns no error

The server that doesn't work is running php5.5 and the server that does work is on php5.4

The various posts have suggested magic_quotes could be a problem, but as far as I can see magic_quotes was disabled since 5.4 and I have confirmed neither server has Magic_Quotes enabled.

Where this gets even more interesting, is that a json_decode on a json object from a Facebook web service is working correctly. So it appears that somewhere, there is a mismatch in the settings of my servers.

I've tried comparing the phpinfo() of both servers but to no avail,but others might have an idea of what settings are most likely to effect this.

The only other thing I could think of is are there likely to be any apache/.htaccess settings I Should look into for this?

The version that doesn't work has the following in phpinfo under the json setting

```
json support    enabled
json version    1.3.6
JSON-C headers version  0.11
JSON-C library version  0.11
```

and the version that is working has

```
json

json support    enabled
json version    1.2.1
```

I appreciate there's no code here or the json, but I can't post the json that isn't working unfortunately and in any case, other valid json from a Facebook WS call is working!

```
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5);

            $headers = array();
        $headers[] = 'Accept: */*';
        $headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding:';
        $headers[] = 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8';
        $headers[] = 'Cache-Control: no-cache';
        $headers[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36';
        $headers[] = 'skip-cache:true';


        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);


    curl_close($ch);
   var_dump($result); // returns valid jsonString
var_dump(json_decode($result),true); //return nothing
```

The only other obvious differences between the servers are: 
the doesn't work server is on curl 7.4.0 and is 64bit php
the server that does work is on curl 7.21.0 and is 32bit php

EDIT****
calling json_decode twice on the same string seems to decode it correctly, I have no idea why this is but will update if I find out
Thanks

Comment: Where is the code you are using?

Comment: I've added the code that makes the call, but as I stated in my question the exact same code works on a different server

Comment: Have you tried [`json_last_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php)? If you calculate the [`sha1`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php) of `$result`, is it the same on both servers?

Comment: check if the JSON string is UTF-8, maybe with mb_detect_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', true);  or see what http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-last-error.php kicks out.

Comment: the sha1 does appear to be the same and mb_detect_encoding is fine for UTF-8

Comment: json_last_error returns 0

Comment: Can you include a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which includes the JSON that's causing the issue?  Without the JSON itself, we can only guess at what may be causing the issue.